# Kinect xbox 360

Tags: c++, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am new on using a Kinect sensor, I have Kinect XBOX 360 and I need to use it to get a real moving body 3D positions. I need to use it with c++ and openCV. I could not find anything helpful on the web. So, please if anyone can give me some advice or if there any code for opening Kinect XBOX 360 with c++ to start with I will appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this library: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect . If you don't have to use C++ obviously the C# drivers for the xbox Kinect by Microsoft are quite useful.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation:)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use OpenNI (https://structure.io/openni) for this. It will make your life infinitely easier. I believe you can even compile OpenCV with OpenNI support out of the box.

You'll probably also want to download and compile PCL (http://pointclouds.org/), which will make managing and manipulating the 3D data a lot easier.

To build a cohesive 3D "world", you'll want to use a fusion library like KinectFusion, which is actually baked into PCL already (https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/gpu/kinfu).

For object recognition, you'll want to use a classifier, of which OpenCV and PCL have many.

There are a plethora of tutorials and examples using the Kinect as an RGBD source.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take your advice and start with openni. My application is that I have a real (not virtual) moving object and I need to know its center position in 3D. the stroke for motion is about 1 meter.